# VS-Code, using regex in Find All (Ctrl + Shift + F)

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I am unable to use regex in the Find All. I have turned regex on but it is not finding any results

I am looking for code that is:

```
returnValue = !$(someClass.someVariable).isDisplayed();
```

with the part *someClass.someVariable* being the wild card in my case and I am trying to use the regex:

```
returnValue = !$(.*)isDisplayed();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using regexp, you have to escape special characters, — in your case, `$`, `(`, `)`, and `.`:

```
returnValue = !\$\(.*\)\.isDisplayed\(\);
```

Comment: By using the backslash? This didn't work.
returnValue = !\$\\(.*\\).isDisplayed();

Comment: Thanks, saw the () at the end too... Thanks. saved me the rest of the day ‍♂️

Comment: I sometimes forget about parentheses too :)